# How to convert a False or True boolean values inside nested python dictionary into javascript in Django template?

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

This is my views.py:

```
    context = {
        "fas": fas_obj,

    }

    # TemplateResponse can only be rendered once
    return render(request, "project_structure.html", context)
```

In the project_structure.html and javascript section:

```
const pp = {{ fas|safe }};
```

I get an error here. because fas contains a False or True boolean value somewhere deep inside. fas is complicated and has lists of dictionaries with nested dictionaries.

What did work is I did this:

```
    context = {
        "fas": fas_obj,
        # need a fas_json version for the javascript part 
        # because of the boolean in python doesn't render well in javascript
        "fas_json": json.dumps(fas_obj),
```

I know now I have two versions because I need the original version for the other part of the template.

In the javascript:

```
const pp = {{fas_json|safe}};
```

Is there an easier way than passing the original and the json version?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const pp = JSON.parse("{{fas_json|safe}}");
```

Answer (score 0):

To transfer nested dictionaries from python to javascript, I would recommend to use this:

```
const pp = JSON.parse("{{fas_json|json_escape}}");
```

This function take care of the format and fixes special character and specific keyword issues.